# Calling ListView.notifyDatasetChanged() every second

Tags: android

I have a ListView which I need to redraw once a second. So I tried having my MainActivity implement Runnable and calling notifyDatasetChanged() from run(). Then I created a ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor to run the MainActivity once a second. But now I'm getting CalledFromWrongThreadExceptions. How can I circumvent this?

Comment: why do you need to call it so often?

Comment: @deville Because the ListView contains times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So not really sure what you need this for, but you should just use the `Handler` attached to the main thread instead of using a `ThreadPoolExecutor`. The reason is that you cannot draw within the context or call `notifyDataSetChanged()` from any other thread other than the main thread.

Try starting the process by initially:

`listView.postDelayed(mRunnable, 1000);` since each view is attached to the thread it was attached to the context with, the main thread in this case. So this is a nice convenient method.

Inside **MainActivity**:

```
private Runnable mRunnable = new Runnable() {
   public void run() {
       mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
       listView.postDelayed(this, 1000);
   }
};
```

Comment: I don't understand what mRunnable is. You mean I should create a new class that implements Runnable, and pass it the listView through the constructor?

Comment: no mRunnable is just an instance variable, probably in your activity.

Comment: An instance variable of what class..?

Comment: Whichever class has the listView instance probably.

Comment: Wait, notifyDataSetChanged is an Adapter method, not a ListView method. And Adapters don't have a postDelayed method.

Comment: Sorry I was doing this more as a general thing at first. Sorry wasn't meant to be verbatum

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be to do the following:

Call the following method `notifyDataSetChangedEverySecond()` once. It sets a timer that gets called every 1000ms.

```
private void notifyDataSetChangedEverySecond() {
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            listview.notifyDatasetChanged();
        }
    },0,1000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use handler instead of ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor, because it creates thread. Or you can just update your ui thread by using runOnUiThread method of context, like this:

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
   public void run() {
      listView.notifyDataSetChanged();
   }
}
```

Use this method where you call notifyDataSetChanged and get error...

Answer (score 0):

```
new Timer().scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            generateData();

            // notifydataset Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views
            MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });
        }
    }, new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()), 1000);
```

this working fine with me